# What is the best way to store sliced arguments in Bash?

Tags: bash, arguments

Example

```
>>./my_script.sh a b c
```

If I try to `echo` argument `2` - `...`, I may do

```
>>echo "${@:2}"
a b c
```

And if i want to store `${@:2}` in variable, these methods will not work

```
my_params=${@:2}
```

or

```
my_params="${@:2}"
```

But this way is work

```
my_params="$(echo ${@:2})"
```

I can feel an ugliness of this way. So, my questions are

1. What is the proper way to store a sliced arguments?
2. How to assign those sliced arguments to a variable?
3. How to reuse it as parameters of another function again?

Comment: I think bash just sets `my_params` to `"b c"` in all 3 cases above.  What is working / not working are you thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original Bourne shell, only the positional argument list was available for this. Fortunately, modern derivatives have an array variable type specifically for this kind of situation.

```
array=("${@[2:]}")  # note parentheses for array
echo "${array[0]}" # first arg of array
command "${array[@]}" # pass array as quoted arguments
```